# How can I check if two keys are pressed at once?

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    //enter key adds a task
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code === 13) {
        var taskName = document.getElementById("task_name").value;
        var dueDate = document.getElementById("due_date").value;
        $("#list").append("<div class='task'>" + taskName + "<textarea class='note_input' placeholder='Notes' rows='2'></textarea>" + "<br>" + "<div class='due'>" + "Due: " + dueDate + "</div>" + "</div>");
        $("h1").effect("pulsate", 1000);
    }
    //checking if alt and c keys are both pressed
    var clearKeys = {
alt: false,
  c: false,
    };
if (code === 18) {
    clearKeys.alt = true;
} else if (code === 67) {
    clearKeys.c = true;
}
if (clearKeys.alt === true && clearKeys.c === true) {
    $(".task").fadeOut("slow");
}
    //resetting the values of clearKeys.alt and clearKeys.c
    window.onkeyup = function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 18) {
        clearKeys.alt = false;
    } else if (code === 67) {
        clearKeys.c = false;
    }
    };
};
```

I made this project in JS Bin. [You can check it out here.](http://jsbin.com/heqelu/1/edit?html,js,output)
When I press the enter key, it works fine. But when I want to clear the list (alt + c) it won't work. The code looks fine to me, and the editor didn't show any errors, so I can't figure out where went wrong.

Comment: Look into [event.altKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.altKey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    code == e.keyCode || e.which;
    if( e.altKey && code == 67 ) {
        //alt+c
    }
};
```